# Using glob to complete a filename (python)

Tags: python-2.7

The contents of the file `myfilepaths`is:

```
/current/0.e_head/10000000d.000000002__head
/current/0.13_head/10000008.000000001__head
..(cont'd)
```

The actual filenames are:

```
/current/0.e_head/10000000d.000000002__head_918293
/current/0.13_head/10000008.000000001__head_9891283
..(cont'd)
```

My code is:

```
filepath = '/path/to/directory/myfilepaths'
location = raw_input('Where is the file? ')

with open(filepath, 'r') as mf:
    for line in mf:
    nline = line.replace("\n", "")
#   cline = glob.glob(nline + '*')  #PROBLEM LINE
    path_obj = os.path.join(location + str(nline))
    obj_stats = os.stat(path_obj)
```

What I am looking to do is to employ glob to complete the filename for me, as the end of the filename is not deterministic enough for it to be hardcoded. The `location` created via raw_input typically is something like /var/local/ etc.

At the moment, what if I use the code pasted here, I get the error message:

```
 no such file or directory: '/var/local/0.e_head/1000000d.000000002_head'
```

If I delete the comment and replace `nline` with `cline` in `path_obj` I get:

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory '/var/local[]'

Now I've seen a lot on SO which shows how to use glob to match certain files such as *.txt and so on, but I haven't seen anything which uses glob to find the end of search criteria

Comment: glob returns a list, could you not use `__head` with a pattern to just find them all or are there some you don't want?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - yes unfortunately there are some filenames which are similar but are not relevant, which is why the selected ones are being read from an input file to filter.

Comment: I added an answer, try that and see how you go. If the path is right and the file exists it should work fine

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  I got a SyntaxError pointing to obj_stats after replicating your code in my script, would this be the correct error message if the file didn't exist or would it mean something else? (EDIT: I think there was a missing ')' after the path_obj. Got a NameError now

Comment: Yep , there was a missing parents, make sure you  import os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*glob* returns a list so calling str on it is not going to work even if you found a match, you need to also join the file name to the path when you are searching:

```
from glob import iglob

with open(filepath, 'r') as mf:
    for line in mf:
        path_obj = next(iglob(os.path.join(location, line.strip() + '*')))
        obj_stats = os.stat(path_obj)
```

Once the path is correct glob should find the file just fine, the only issue is if you had overlapping patterns, the first part of each file name must be unique for your logic to work. I also presume  `'/path/to/directory/myfilepaths'` is a file that lists the partial file names.

Comment: sorry to bother you again Padraic, but I think there may be a fault in the regular expression answer, as it stands, if I print path_obj - it actually outputs the path for the contents of the directory specified within location input, rather than delving into the folders using the lines from filepath file

Comment: I think we may have crossed wires, what is in the file and how does it relate to location?

Comment: Forget the regex, I see there are subdirectories in the file path file, anyway the glob logic will work fine once you have the path right